# Is there a nicer way to use nested SASS & selectors in this scenario?

Tags: css, sass

I need to select a child of an element but it's based on :last-of-type on the parent.

I've tried:

```
&:last-of-type {
  &__content {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Which doesn't work because of the way SASS constructs.

I've ended up with:

```
.assignment-selection {
  &__list-item {
    &__content {
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      .assignment-selection {
        &__list-item {
          &__content {
            border-bottom: 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a nicer/more efficient way of writing this?

Comment: I think `.parent:last-of-type>.child` in regular CSS should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
&:last-of-type > &__content {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with regular CSS like this (if this is an option)

css:

```
.parent>li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent:last-of-type>li {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <li class="child">text</li>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <li class="child">text</li>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <li class="child">text</li>
</div>
```

this is the related fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugskwa7t/

Answer (score 0):

Just because **SASS** allows nesting doesn't mean we should always nest since it makes **CSS** a bit unreadable, even more so in the Browser's dev tools which makes code harder to debug.

```
.assignment-selection {
  &__list-item {
    &__content {
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
  }
}

.assignment-selection:last-of-type {
  &__list-item {
    &__content {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}
```